# Capturing and taking a screenshot of a window in a loop

Tags: c#, image, serialization

I am capturing a window of my own choice, and taking a screenshot of it constantly in a loop. Latency and speed is everything.

It's very capable, but I hope it can be improved.

```
var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(prcname)[0];
IntPtr hwnd = proc.MainWindowHandle;
RECT rc;  
NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
NativeMethods.PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);
gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
gfxBmp.Dispose();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

return new MemoryStream(Lz4.CompressBytes(ms.GetBuffer()));
```

I will set a name `prcname` which will be the name of a process, for example, Internet Explorer. It will then hook on to that and save it as a bitmap and then .bmp (or other).

I then return the memory stream , and then I can do what I want with it (lz4 is used here to compress, which is very fast and lossless so it works pretty well).

Here are the `Import`s used:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);
```

Then there is the `RECT` class, which is enormous, and I did not write it. I took it and reused this code for my own purposes, but `RECT` has been untouched, as I don't feel safe messing around with it.

Now, is there a way to improve the speed? Preferably I would like to improve the latency, meaning the frame it lags behind.

I am willing to try something else if user32 is not enough for this, so I'm open for suggestions and examples on that.

Can this code be improved?

```
NetSerializer.Serializer.Serialize(tcpcap.GetStream(), PrintWindow(process));
PrintWindow(process).Dispose();


panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(new Lz4DecompressionStream((MemoryStream)NetSerializer.Serializer.Deserialize(tt1.GetStream())));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, yes, you're holding on to a bunch of `IDisposable` objects which should be dealt with by employing the `using` statement:

```
IntPtr hwnd;

using (var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(prcname)[0])
{
    hwnd = proc.MainWindowHandle;
}

RECT rc;
NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
{
    using (Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
        try
        {
            NativeMethods.PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);
        }
        finally
        {
            gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
        }
    }

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return new MemoryStream(Lz4.CompressBytes(ms.GetBuffer()));
    }
}
```

Plus, the `MemoryStream` you return should be `Dispose()`'d be the calling code.

Comment: Not quite familiar what´s going on there. Why will "Using" be faster then just using variables around the place? (New to this).  And how can i dispose the last memory stream in the calling code?  Thanks

Comment: I updated the code to show where i use it, tell me if it´s correct.

Comment: @Zerowalker My understanding is by using the using statements you are guaranteed even on failure (within the code block) that the Dispose method will be called thus releasing resources.

Comment: Ah well that sounds good. I am a bit lacking when it comes to properly use and dispose.  But i don´t get how i am supposed to dispose the Memory Stream i am using, as disposing it like i put above, didn´t do anything but slow it down.

Comment: @Zerowalker well, to be fair, I never claimed it would be faster :) You asked if the code could be improved and here's the improvement. However, using the `using` deterministic disposal pattern, you're probably relieving memory pressure.